# iOS OpenGL layer and UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, uiscrollview

I'm creating a drawing app on the iPad where the user can draw and scroll through the drawing. (Think of a canvas 4000 pixels wide with a view port width of 1024) At the moment, I'm using OpenGL for the drawing, and with a width of 1024, it works great. When I change the frame size of the UIView to 4000, I get "failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6". When I reduced it to a width of 2000, I ended up getting "wacky" results. I know I can manipulate the frame correctly, as having a frame width of 500 creates the correct result.

I was also thinking of leaving the width 1024 and moving the camera of the OpenGL layer, but how would that work with the UIScrollView that I setup? So I'm unsure on what to do at the moment. Any advice?

Thanks in advance

P.S. The code is largely based of GLPaint sample Apple provides [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Hi, I'm working on the same problem, but I can't get my implementation to work. Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: This is a good session which helps: http://asciiwwdc.com/2012/sessions/223

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'd be best off with the scheme you suggest towards the end — keeping the OpenGL view static and outside of the scroll view, and moving its contents so as to match the movement of the scroll view.

Assuming you're using a `GLKView`, implement your `glkView:drawInRect:` so that it gets the `contentOffset` (and, probably, the `bounds`) properties from your scroll view and draws appropriately. E.g. (pretending you're using GLES 1.0 just because the matrix manipulation methods are so well known):

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // displayArea will be the area the scroll view is
    // currently displaying; taking just the bounds would
    // likely be fine too
    CGRect displayArea;
    displayArea.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;
    displayArea.size = scrollView.bounds.size;

    // assuming (0, 0) in the GL view is in the centre,
    // we'll adjust things so that it's in the corner ala
    // UIKit
    CGPoint centre = CGPointMake(
           displayArea.origin.x + displayArea.size.width*0.5f,
           displayArea.origin.y + displayArea.size.height*0.5f);

    glPushMatrix();

        // apply the scroll as per the scroll view
        // so that its centre is aligned with our centre
        glTranslatef(-centre.x, -centre.y, -1);

                /* rest of drawing here */

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Then connect yourself as a delegate to the scrollview and just perform:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [glView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

To ensure the GL redraws whenever the scroll view is scrolled.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend to do your zooming in panning with your OpenGL camera instead of trying to use it in a UIScrollView. It will be a little more work to set up, but ultimately the way to go IMHO.